# Create an iPhone app to have multiple users in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

I want to create an application using which we can create multiple users in an `iOS` Device. Just like multiple users in a computer. Every user should be able to have separate applications, separate settings etc.
Tried to find the starting point for this app but no luck.

Can anyone tell me from where to start and how can we implement this **system/feature** in `iPhone`.
If we have to make this app only for jailbreak iPhones, no problem.

Comment: yes good definition but what you have to tried ??

Comment: @TheKing Tried to look for a starting point. but not getting one yet.
I've worked mostly on general purpose apps. but this app needs interaction with iphone settings and playing with iphone internals.

Comment: is it possible to impelement something like this without jailbreak ?

Answer (score 2):

It is all about implementing a correct ***primary-foreign key relationship*** in DB-schema(sqlite).
Storing and retrieving data with respect to Pk-Fk relationship

**For instance**

Have a user table

> *Table Name* : User
>
> *Columns*    : userRef,userId,userType

(userRef should be a primary key)

Then all the subtables should store and retrieve data using the userRef in Primary and foreign key relationships.

> *Table Name* : Account_balance
>
> *Columns*    : userRef,account_BalId,balanceAmount

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It is better you create a CoreData DB for your app and maintain a User and permission matrix.

Say like this:

```
>              Write Files         Edit Files        Delete     
> 
> Admin           Y                   Y               Y
> 
> Guest           Y                   N               N
> 
> Developer       Y                   Y               N
```

You gotta come up with such a matrix and translate this to a Core Data DB, that maintains the user details and his permissions.